# TypeError: bytes or ASCII string of length 1 expected in QByteArray?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I would expect this to work. But it does not. What did i wrong?

```
    from  PyQt5.QtCore import  QByteArray

    str = 'foobar'
    b = bytes(str, 'UTF-8')

    print (b)
    print (len(b))

    arr = QByteArray(len(b), b)
```

But i get:

```
b'foobar'
6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyqt_wtf_again.py", line 9, in <module>
    arr = QByteArray(len(b), b)
TypeError: bytes or ASCII string of length 1 expected
```

Shouldn't this just work?

Comment: Is there a reason for needing a `QByteArray`? I ask because the [PyQt5 docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/gotchas.html) say that "If Qt expects a QByteArray then PyQt5 will also accept a bytes" so it seems like there wouldn't be very many cases where you would actually need to convert `bytes` to `QByteArray`.

Comment: Do look at the docs once a while. :P The init funtion has the form `QByteArray( len, byte )` This creates a `QByteArray`, `len` bytes long, filled with `byte`. In your case, you could just do `arr = QByteArray( b )`.

Comment: Solves the problem. Indeed the doc says @ByteArray( len, byte). Which made me believe ( len(b), b ) would be the correct parameters. Seems, one has to look often enough at the docs, to miss the right things ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following are the QByteArray constructors from the [C++ Qt docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qbytearray.html)

```cpp
QByteArray(QByteArray &&other)
QByteArray(const QByteArray &other)
QByteArray(qsizetype size, char ch)
QByteArray(const char *data, qsizetype size = -1)
```

The third one is the one you are using, but that requires a char, not a string. If you change the code to

```py
    from  PyQt5.QtCore import  QByteArray

    str = 'f'
    b = bytes(str, 'UTF-8')

    print (b)
    print (len(b))

    arr = QByteArray(len(b), b)
```

it has no problems, as f is a single character. PyQt is just an interface to the C++ Qt, and so I think the [docs on QByteArray for python](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtCore/QByteArray.html) are just lacking showing this constructor.